# VS Shell Command 'code' install returns 'command not available'

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code

I am attempting to set up VS code and install the shell command 'code'.  When I open up the command line, type in "Shell command" and select the install option, it returns "This command is not available".  How do I get around this?

Running on Mac and I've tried uninstalling it, then installing it. Nothing.  I've tried closing the application and reopening. Nothing.

Shift-Command-P: 
Command line - 
"Shell command: Install 'code' command in PATH"

It should have installed and upon closing and reopening the application, should work.  But instead returns the message "This command is not available"

Comment: How does it make sense to launch VS Code (`code`) in it's own command shell?

Comment: Ken..such a constructive and helpful comment. thanks.

Comment: It is constructive. If you're trying to add `code` to VS Code's own terminal, it makes no sense, which is most likely why it's telling you `This command is not available` - because it makes no sense to launch VS Code inside VS Code's own shell.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but my directions are: launch VS Code -- open command palette (shift-command-P) -- type 'shell command' -- select install 'code'.

Comment: did that procedure and I received this message: Shell command 'code' successfully installed in PATH

Comment: ^^^^ this is for anyone who may run into the hiccup themselves.  We're all learning here

Comment: If you found the answer, post it as your own answer below and accept it.